# How to select data into List<T> instead of DataTable?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

This is how currently I'm selecting data from database:

```
public DataTable GetData()
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable("Table");
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Connection string"))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        command.CommandText = "query string";

        connection.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        adapter.Fill(table);
    }
    return table;
}
```

But it return DataTable and I want to select List instead of DataTable. Like this:

```
public List<MyClass> GetData()
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable("Table");
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Connection string"))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        command.CommandText = "query string";

        connection.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        adapter.Fill(table);
    }
    ...
    return [List of MyClass];
}
```

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you definitely want to use low-level ADO.NET calls rather than LINQ to SQL or the Entity Framework?

Comment: I'm not sure. But I think low level ADO.NET will be faster.

Comment: Yeah, ADO.NET will be faster, but this speed gain makes difference for your enviroment?

Comment: Faster code is always better.

Comment: No, it's really not. Code that is maintainable and readable is generally better - you can squeeze out tiny optimizations at the cost of simplicity when you've found where the bottlenecks *really* are. If you're after the *absolute fastest code possible*, why aren't you writing in hand-tweaked assembly?

Comment: What do you want `T` to be? A list of `DataRow` objects, or something else?

Comment: @JamesJohnson No not list of DataRow. I want the list of my custom class.

Comment: Was my answer helpful to you to get List of your `MyClass`?

Comment: @jams Yes it is. dapper-dot-net was helpful link. Unfortunately I don't have vote up privilege.

Comment: Actually I want to just ask for curiosity, nothing more than that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend you to use [dapper-dot-net](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/), if you do not want to dig into LINQ to SQL or Entity Framework. Fumbling around yourself with `IDataReader` to materialise your result isn't worth the effort in most cases.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use the `DataRowCollection` to populate a list of custom objects, you could use LINQ and an object initializer:

```
var lst = table.AsEnumerable().Select(r =>
    new MyObject
    {
        FirstProperty = r.Field<int>("FirstProperty"),
        OtherProperty = r.Field<string>("OtherProperty")
    }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this code.

```
public List<MyClass> GetData()
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable("Table");
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Connection string"))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        command.CommandText = "query string";
        connection.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        adapter.Fill(table);
        List<MyClass> list=new List<MyClass>();
        foreach(DataRow row in table)
        {
            MyClass instance = new MyClass();
            instance.ID = row["ID"];
            //similarly for rest of the properties

            list.Add(instance);
        }

    }

    return list;
}
```

Comment: dapper-dot-net was helpful link. Unfortunately I don't have vote up privilege.

Comment: -1. There is literally no need to write code like this any more.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the ADO.NET approach - you'll get back a data Table and you can convert it to a List or IEnumberable.

Alternatively, you could look into ORM tools like nHibernate or use LINQ to SQL