# How to fill List<String> with SqlDataAdapter?

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures

I am trying to fill List with SqlDataAdapter. But i am not able to do it.Is there any other method to fill List of string apart from Data Adapter. Please help me out to solve this problem.Thanks in advance.

This is my code:

```
public List<String> JSONDataAll()
        {
            List<String> Users = new List<String>();
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_sample_Proc", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(Users);
        }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to select data into List<T> instead of DataTable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10505733/how-to-select-data-into-listt-instead-of-datatable)

Comment: You need to fill a datatable first, then you create a `List<string>` from your datatable.

Comment: What is the return of the Stored Procedure? Could you add the code of the SP?

Comment: Yeah its working now.

Comment: Whats up with the Edit ? If you need to ask a new question, then don't modify your current question. Ask a new one.

Comment: Sorry..I will post in new Question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simplest way would be read your data through `SqlDataReader` and then fill your list iterating your resultset. Like:

```
public List<String> JSONDataAll()
{
    List<String> Users = new List<String>();
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("connectionString"))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_sample_Proc", con))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Users.Add(reader.GetString(0)); //Specify column index 
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return Users;
}
```

In your current code you are trying to fill `List<string>` using `DataAdapter`. You can't do that. Instead you can fill a `DataTable` and then get a `List<string>` like:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(dt);
Users = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(r => r.Field<string>("ColumnName"))
    .ToList();
```

**But, You shouldn't do that**. It would result in multiple iterations, first for filling up the `DataTable` and second for creating `List<string>`

Comment: @Habib can you pls help to get same thing in using LINQ.I have updated my LINQ Code. I am getting conversion error.

Comment: @user3336505, that has nothing to do with the current question's scope. If you have new problem then ask a new question. You are getting the error because you are selecting an *anonymous* type and then trying to return `List<string>`. How can a `List<string>` have a `Key` and an integer value of total count ? Not really sure why you are using `GroupBy`

Comment: I want data in the form of Key and value.

Comment: @user3336505, you can't return an anonymous type, You can create a new class, with two properties for Key and Count and project your query result to that class's object and return `List<ThatClass>`., See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073319/returning-anonymous-type-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 7):

Please try this

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
Users = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(n => n.Field<string>(0)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If types in your database are different, you can use this, it will accept all types.

```
var dataTable= new DataTable();
dataTable.Fill(dataTable);
var users = dataTable.AsEnumerable().Select(n => n.ItemArray).ToList();
```

You will obtain result as a nice list of elements:

```
[[3,"Adam","Smith","adamSmith@gmail.com","Kokos",1],
[5,"Dominika","Smith","dominikaSmith@gmail.com","Domis",2]]
```